# How can I make two() to ignore the same cases as one()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

How can I make the program to skip those results where 'it does not pass'. `one()` ignores some cases.  `two()` forgets to ignore them. It should not iterate over "NO PASS" cases.

```
import random
def percentage(a, b):
    return 100 * (float(a) / float(b))
def one(a, b, c):
    if percentage(a, b) <= 40:
        print("%d PASS" % c)
    elif 40 < percentage(a, b) <= 80:
        print("%d PASS" % c)
    else: # ONE() IGNORES THESE CASES. 
        pass 
def two(a, c): # HOW CAN I MAKE THIS FUNCTION TO IGNORE THE SAME CASES AS ONE()
    if a%2 == 0:
        print("%d EVEN" % c)
    elif a%2 != 0:
        print("%d ODD" % c)

randomlist = []
for i in range(0,5):
    n = random.randint(1,500)
    randomlist.append(n)

test1 = random.randrange(1, 500)
test2 = random.randrange(1, 500)

for c, a in enumerate(randomlist): 
    one(test1, test2, c+1)
for c, a in enumerate(randomlist):
    two(a, c+1)
```

Comment: In `one`, your first two cases are the same. Is that intentional?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. In `one`, there are three possible results for a given `a` value, it's either less than 40, between 40 and 80, or greater than 80 (this last one is ignored). But in `two` there are only two categories, even and odd. What other kind of number do you expect to exist? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Return from `two()` if `percentage(a, b) > 80` _before_ checking for evenness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the first function as a filter and only pass list values to the second function if they pass the filter. For this you need to return something from the first function. Here is one way to do that:

```
import random
def percentage(a, b):
    return 100 * (float(a) / float(b))

def one(a, b, c):
    if percentage(a, b) <= 40:
        print("%d PASS" % c)
        return True
    elif 40 < percentage(a, b) <= 80:
        print("%d PASS" % c)
        return True
    else:
        return False

def two(a, c):
    if a%2 == 0:
        print("%d EVEN" % c)
    elif a%2 != 0:
        print("%d ODD" % c)

randomlist = []
for i in range(0,5):
    n = random.randint(1,500)
    randomlist.append(n)

test1 = random.randrange(1, 500)
test2 = random.randrange(1, 500)

randomlist_filtered = []
for c, a in enumerate(randomlist): 
    passed = one(test1, test2, c+1)
    if passed:
        randomlist_filtered.append(a)
for c, a in enumerate(randomlist_filtered):
    two(a, c+1)
```

Output of a random run:

```
1 PASS
2 PASS
3 PASS
4 PASS
5 PASS
1 ODD
2 ODD
3 EVEN
4 ODD
5 EVEN
```

Note that the indices of the items are different in the second loop. If you want to keep the indices, you could run both functions within the same loop or preserve the entries together with their respective indices in the filtered list. I didn't fix it because to be honest, I do not know why you even want the indices (which are generated by `enumerate`)

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks a lot sir, much appreciated!